# Using git difftool for files comparsion in Debian Linux v. 10 (buster)

Tags: git, debian, debian-buster, difftool, git-difftool

In Debian Linux v. 9 I use following command to do files comparison and this command is working OK:

`git difftool /file/a /file/b`

In Debian Linux v. 10 I use this command in the same way and have following error:

`fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Help me, please, resolve it.

PS: I don't use any git-repositories in the work, just only difftool from git.

Comment: Is the git version the same on both devices? Is there a `.git` directory in your Debian 9 device?

Comment: @dan1st, no in first example git's version: 2.11.0, in second: 2.20.1; no, no .git directory in both examples...

Answer (score 0):

You need `git` version 2.22.0 or higher. In 2.22.0 `git difftool` can run outside a repository. See https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.22.0.txt

Comment: Thanks you! So, in Git v. 2.20.0 I have no parameters to run following command: `git difftool`, outside Git repository?

Comment: @mshta Alas, no.